# Error when trying to call a method

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a method.  Based on what I have read and watched I had though this was the way to create and then call a method but I am not too sure if I am doing it right.  I received and error when I complied so If you have any suggestions on how to better the code that would be much appreciated.

Here is the error:

> Error: can not find symbol.

And it gave me about 10 of these errors all in referance to the arrays in public static void getLabelData() where I tried to create a method.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class MailOrderCall
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    streetAddress, city, state, zip.
    String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];
    String numBoxesInput;
    int numBoxes;
    String enterAnother = "Y";
    int counter;



    getLabelData();

    while(enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {
        counter = 1;
        // begin the inner loop to display a label and increment the counter
        while(counter <= numBoxes)
        {
            System.out.println(nameAddressArray[0] + " " + nameAddressArray[1] + " " + nameAddressArray[2]);
            System.out.println(nameAddressArray[3]);
            System.out.println(nameAddressArray[4] + ", " + nameAddressArray[5] + " " + nameAddressArray[6]);
            System.out.println("Box " + counter + " of " + numBoxes);
            System.out.println();
            counter = counter + 1;
        } // end while

        // ask the user if finished entering mail orders
        enterAnother = " ";   // initialize the variable to something other than "Y" before sending the prompt
        enterAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to produce more labels? Y or N");

        // validate input for enterAnother... keep them here until they enter Y, y, N, or n
        while (!enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            enterAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid Response. Please enter Y or N.",
                                                        "DATA ENTRY ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } // end while

        if(enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            // if the user said they have more, then send prompts to read the next mail order input from user
        getLabelData();
        } // end if
    } // end while
// successfully terminate the application
system.exit(0);
} // end main()

 public static void getLabelData() {
            nameAddressArray[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter     title (Mr., Ms., Dr., etc.): ");
                nameAddressArray[1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name: ");
                nameAddressArray[2] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter lastname: ");
                nameAddressArray[3] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter street address: ");
                nameAddressArray[4] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter city: ");
                nameAddressArray[5] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter state (IL, MO, etc.): ");
                nameAddressArray[6] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter zip (e.g., 62025): ");

                numBoxesInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of boxes in the order:");
        numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesInput);
}


} // end class
```

I'm pretty new at this so I'm sorry if my code is a total disaster I'm just tryna figure out why it's giving me an error.

Comment: You cannot access the local variables of one method (`main`) from another method. Local variables only exist in the block where they were declared.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you are trying to access a variable that isn't available in your `getLabelData` function. if you want to use a variable in multiple functions, you should declare it in the scope of your entire class, like so:

```
public class MailOrderCallEMH {

    String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];
    String numBoxesInput;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Also, `streetAddress, city, state, zip.` doesn't look like valid java syntax. You should probably declare those variables normally:

```
// Replace Object by the type you want
Object streetAddress;
Object city;
Object state;
Object zip;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`nameAddressArray` was declared as a local variable in your `main` method.  If you declare a variable inside of a method, then you can only access it from that method.

If you want `nameAddressArray` to be accessible from any method within your class, declare it as a member variable of `MailOrderCallEMH` by declaring it inside of your class, but outside of a method like this

```
public class MailOrderCallEMH
{
    // Since this is a member of the class, you can use it from any method within this class
    static String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       // code
    }

    public static void getLabelData() 
    {
       nameAddressArray[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter     title (Mr., Ms., Dr., etc.): ");
       // and so on
    }
}
```

Also, notice how I declared `nameAddressArray` as `static`.  The reason for that is that member variables that are accessed in a static method have to be static as well.  Since you're starting out with Java, I recommend reading about what `static` does.  In general, the use of static variables and methods is discouraged.

The other way to do this is to pass `nameAddressArray` as a parameter to `getLabelData`

```
public class MailOrderCallEMH
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];
       getLabelData(nameAddressArray);
       System.out.println(nameAddressArray[0] + " " + nameAddressArray[1] + " " + nameAddressArray[2]);
    }

    public static void getLabelData(String nameAddressArray[]) 
    {
       nameAddressArray[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter     title (Mr., Ms., Dr., etc.): ");
       // and so on
    }
}
```

It's important to note that in this example, the reason that `getLabelData` is able to update a variable that is declared inside of `main` is that the variable is being passed by reference (as opposed to being passed by value).  That's another important concept that you should make sure that you become familiar with.